# How to rebind view in a class that extends RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to rebind a view when `closeDialog()` is called. I assume that I should somehow mark the view as dirty. If this is the correct course of action to take how would I do this? My code:

```js
public final class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingViewHolder>
  implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
 private SettingsFragmentView mView;
 private Context mContext;
 private ArrayList<SettingsItem> mSettings;

 private SettingsItem mClickedItem;
 private int mSeekbarProgress;

 private AlertDialog mDialog;
 private TextView mTextSliderValue;

 public SettingsAdapter(SettingsFragmentView view, Context context)
 {
  mView = view;
  mContext = context;
 }
  
  // Unrelated code removed here
  
   @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
 {
  if (mClickedItem instanceof SingleChoiceSetting)
  {
   SingleChoiceSetting scSetting = (SingleChoiceSetting) mClickedItem;

   int value = getValueForSingleChoiceSelection(scSetting, which);
   MenuTag menuTag = scSetting.getMenuTag();
   if(menuTag != null)
   {
    if (menuTag.isGCPadMenu())
    {
     mView.onGcPadSettingChanged(menuTag, value);
    }

    if (menuTag.isWiimoteMenu())
    {
     mView.onWiimoteSettingChanged(menuTag, value);
    }

    if (menuTag.isWiimoteExtensionMenu())
    {
     mView.onExtensionSettingChanged(menuTag, value);
    }
   }

   // Get the backing Setting, which may be null (if for example it was missing from the file)
   IntSetting setting = scSetting.setSelectedValue(value);
   if (setting != null)
   {
    mView.putSetting(setting);
   }
   else
   {
    if (scSetting.getKey().equals(SettingsFile.KEY_VIDEO_BACKEND_INDEX))
    {
     putVideoBackendSetting(which);
    }
    else if (scSetting.getKey().equals(SettingsFile.KEY_WIIMOTE_EXTENSION))
    {
     putExtensionSetting(which, Character.getNumericValue(scSetting.getSection().charAt(scSetting.getSection().length() - 1)));
    }
   }

   closeDialog();
  }
  else if (mClickedItem instanceof StringSingleChoiceSetting)
  {
   StringSingleChoiceSetting scSetting = (StringSingleChoiceSetting) mClickedItem;
   String value = scSetting.getValueAt(which);
   StringSetting setting = scSetting.setSelectedValue(value);
   if (setting != null)
   {
    mView.putSetting(setting);
   }

   closeDialog();
  }
  else if (mClickedItem instanceof SliderSetting)
  {
   SliderSetting sliderSetting = (SliderSetting) mClickedItem;
   if (sliderSetting.getSetting() instanceof FloatSetting)
   {
    float value;

    if (sliderSetting.getKey().equals(SettingsFile.KEY_OVERCLOCK_PERCENT)
      || sliderSetting.getKey().equals(SettingsFile.KEY_SPEED_LIMIT))
    {
     value = mSeekbarProgress / 100.0f;
    }
    else
    {
     value = (float) mSeekbarProgress;
    }

    FloatSetting setting = sliderSetting.setSelectedValue(value);
    if (setting != null)
    {
     mView.putSetting(setting);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    IntSetting setting = sliderSetting.setSelectedValue(mSeekbarProgress);
    if (setting != null)
    {
     mView.putSetting(setting);
    }
   }
  }

  mView.onSettingChanged();
  mClickedItem = null;
  mSeekbarProgress = -1;
 }

 public void closeDialog()
 {
  // I'm guessing that I should mark the view as dirty here  

  if (mDialog != null)
  {
   mDialog.dismiss();
   mDialog = null;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` seems to solve this problem.